# OrientDB: Creating Graph-database through HTTP-API

Tags: rest, graph, objectdb

It seems it is only possible to create document-type databases via the HTTP-api. The [documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-REST.html) omit's information about whether the database will be created as a graph or a documentdatabase, but when creating a vertext, i get the error:

```
Super-class V not exists
```

...which, [as i understand](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/1742), means that the database is a document-type.
Is there any way around this? The */command/* action makes it pretty easy for me to do what I want from C#, if I could only generate a graph-database via HTTP-api...

Is there any way to create a graph-database through the HTTP-API?

Alternatively: Is there another way to create a graph-database from c#? I've tried creating a database via the console, but here i get IllegalArgumentException:

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Storage type 'plocal' is different by storage type in URL
```

..which i cannot find any explenation for

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Btw, I'm running it on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error message when I typed in the following command:

> create database REMOTE:localhost/petshop root aaaa plocal document

Solution:
I had to write it in lower case:

> create database remote:localhost/petshop root aaaa plocal document

Comment: Thanks for the input - I've abandoned OrientDB (this question was posted in a "find the tech we want to use"-phase) in favor of ArangoDB, so I can't really verify.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to have that using `POST http://localhost:2480/database/<db name>/plocal/graph`

I did found it experimentally. Did not found that in documentation which is a bit strange.
Tested on version 2.1.7